# Did T-Bag's father sexually abuse him?

Tags: character, prison-break

In season 2, episode 17 of Prison Break, T-Bag's father is angry at young T-Bag because he isn't getting good grades at school.

Then T-Bag's father touches T-Bag on the leg and closes the door.

I know that can mean a lot of things, but can we assume based on that that T-Bag's father was sexually abusing him?

Comment: That scene *strongly implies* that was the case (honestly, I'm not sure there's anything else you could infer from that scene), but I don't know if it's ever explicitly stated in any other episodes.

Comment: Yes, scene strongly implies and it's logical to assume , but there's no word in other episodes about that. That's why I'm asking. In fact there's little known about T-Bag's past, which is quite disappointment as T-Bag is one of the strongest characters in series. I'm searching for other proofs. Is there other signs, for example in "Breakout Kings". I haven't watched , bit I know the same T-Bag is there and the same Robbert knepper plays that character. Or that's out of canon. Or in the 'Prison Break' again, may I have missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, he definitely did.

Besides that flashback you mentioned when his father touches his leg and then closes the door, there's a scene in Season 4 Episode 21 which leaves no doubt: T-Bag is going to rape Sara and she tells him that he's like that, that he was 'damaged' by all those childhood traumas and repeated sexual abuse. That's also why T-Bag thinks he can't have kids; he thinks his sterility is due to the sexual abuse he suffered as a child.

Answer (score 0):

From [Prison Break Wikia](http://prisonbreak.wikia.com/wiki/Riots,_Drills_and_the_Devil,_Part_1_(episode)/Transcript) here is the transcript of Season 1 Episode 6 titled Riots, Drill and the Devil.

> BELLICK: [Approaching T-Bag and speaking more quietly] That's right, Teddy. I read your psych records. About how your daddy raped his mongoloid sister and then nine months later, little Teddy pops out.
>
> [T-Bag is quiet for a moment, suddenly he grabs the gate]
>
> T-BAG: I'm gonna kill you!
>
> [T-Bag goes crazy, the rest of the rioters start yelling and attacking the gate again, Bellick laughs, then bends down and picks something up]

It's evident that T-Bag's father was a pervert and incest. So **Yea**. He sexually abused T-Bag.

Comment: While that prove he was an incestuous pervert, it still does not **prove** he sexually assaulted T-Bag. However, I would wager it's highly likely, with the scene itself strongly implying it

Comment: @BlueMoon93: Exactly my friend. The scene OP described was self explanatory. I was backing up with another example to clarify it.